how to create a custom module and import it in VISUAL STUDIO CODE
i am working on a real time voice cloning project which uses synthesizer, encoder and vocoder. i don't know how to create a custom modules for them. how do i create or where can i get them from and how do i import it in my working space. my project is to create a streamlit application for real time voice cloning which will be combained with text summarization...like u can convert the summarized text to your desired voice
i tried asking ChatGPT and came up with some pretty basic modules but it shows error saying it is object. it also shows error for already existing ones...like..from synthesizer.hparams import Hparams it is something that was already there but i couldn't import itsynthesizer.
